# What's the proper way to get a WPF custom control library to control to display the right style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I'm dipping my toe in the WPF custom control library pool for the first time. I created a project in a separate solution for my custom control which just derives from Control.

In the target App where I want to use the custom control, it  works but doesn't seem to be able to access the default style unless I specifically add a reference in the App.xaml file. I've added the xmlns property so the control itself is available. I'm hoping I'm missing some setting that makes the control more self-contained. So in my target WPF app everything works (function and style) if I add the line shown after the comment in App.xaml:

```
    <Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyStandardStuff.xaml" />
            <!-- How do I avoid having everyone who uses the control having to add the following line?-->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyNewControl;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Given that my custom control library has a Themes folder with a Generic.xaml file containing a style of this form:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyNewControl}">
 <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyNewControl}">
  ...
```

Is there some way to make it work without adding the explicit reference in App.xaml?

### EDIT

Here's the ThemeInfo attribute that was created with the project.

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
//(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
// or application resource dictionaries)
ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
//(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
// app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```

### Specifics on the Answer

I'm not sure this question will come up again because it turns out I did something stupid, but in case it does... I created the WPF Custom Control Library using the VS template. Then I copied and pasted my control class over the the default class that Visual studio created. What I didn't notice is that VS created a static constructor that was doing something very important. This was pointed out in a comment to the answer below. The static constructor should look like this

```
    static MyNewControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyNewControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyNewControl)));
    }
```

Once this was in place I could remove the code I added to the target's resource dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make sure that the xaml file in your control assembly is marked as Page and also make sure that you have the [ThemeInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.themeinfoattribute.aspx) attribute in the assemblyinfo.cs for your control assembly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "make sure that the xaml file in your control assembly is marked as Page". There is no .xaml in the custom control other than the style I mentioned. The control is very simple and is just a .cs file. I created the WPF Custome Library using the standard VS template so I have the default ThemeInfo attribute that it created. I'll add it to the post.

Comment: In your custom control assembly you defined a xaml file - generic.xaml that is under the "themes" folder right. I simply meant that in the properties for that file that the Build Action is "Page". If you create the control using the WPF Custom Control Library template then everything should be there including the Build Action and the attribute.

Comment: Assuming you put a Style that targets your type into that generic.xaml and you left the DefaultStyleKey override in the static ctor and the type it passes is that of your control name (again the WPF Custom Control Library template would work as is) then one shouldn't need to define/reference xaml for your control in the application using your control. It would automatically fallback to the generic.xaml defined within the control assembly.

Comment: OK - I just checked and the Build Action is set to page. But I bet I broke the DefaultStyleKey override you're talking about. I already had my control code so I pasted it in. I'll create a new custom library again and look into that.

Comment: Yes the DefaultStyleKey is what WPF uses to locate the default style for the control. The one that the template would include would look something like this:  `public class CustomControl1 : Control
 {
  static CustomControl1()
  {
   DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
  }
 }`